# Getting (The name 'file' does not exist in the current context) message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, webforms, asp.net-3.5

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the full code behind from the downloaded example, unedited:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String UpPath;
        UpPath = "C:\\UploadedUserFiles";

        if (!Directory.Exists(UpPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\UploadedUserFiles\\");
        }
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < uploads.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile upload = file;

            if (upload.ContentLength == 0)
                continue;

            string c = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName); // We don't need the path, just the name.

        try
            {
            upload.SaveAs("C:\\UploadedUserFiles\\" + c);
            Span1.InnerHtml = "Upload(s) Successful.";
            }
        catch(Exception Exp)
            {
                Span1.InnerHtml = "Upload(s) FAILED.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I've just downloaded a "file uploading" example from www.asp.net:

Link to tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2
Link to download: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/9/869ff08a-1e39-4bab-a303-f7dcedc52427/CS-ASP-MultiFileUpload-CS.zip

and copied the files to my webserver after extracting them.

When I navigate to http://server/uploader/Default.aspx

It creates the folder in the servers c drive successfully, but on the web browser I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'file' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:



Line 29:         for (int i = 0; i < uploads.Count; i++)
Line 30:         {
Line 31:             HttpPostedFile upload = file;
Line 32: 
Line 33:             if (upload.ContentLength == 0)


Source File: c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\uploader\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 31 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3623; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Post the code of the _whole_ method. Where do you declare the `file` variable?

Comment: Added full code behind above.

Comment: Probably you should be getting the specific Item from the uploaded files collection HttpPostedFile upload = uploads.Item[i];

Comment: `HttpPostedFile upload = file;` , where is file coming from it has no reference fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing an undeclared local variable file, you should be retrieving the HttpPostedFile from the uploads "Items" collection using the Item index;

```
HttpPostedFile upload = uploads[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug on the sample code. Try replacing this

```
HttpPostedFile upload = file
```

by

```
HttpPostedFile upload = uploads[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

Along with "Default.aspx" and "Default.aspx.cs",  you need "Default.aspx.Designer.cs" File.
As all the controls are defined with its style in "Designer" file.